# $X_{n}$ converges to $0$ in probability while $\frac{S_{n}}{n}$ doesn't

Tags: probability-theory

I've encountered a problem asking us to give a counterexample that $X_{n}$ converges to $0$ in probability while $\frac{S_{n}}{n}$ doesn't.

I find it easy to find an example in which $X_{n}$ converges to $0$, but not sure about how to show $\frac{S_{n}}{n}$ does not. How to come up with such example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Do you know the Borel Cantelli lemma?

Comment: @PhoemueX but $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges

Comment: Exactly. See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma under "Converse result".

Comment: @PhoemueX I've thought about it. But even if we know $P(E)=1$ where $E=\{{\omega: \omega \in E_{n}}\}$ and $E_{n}=\{{\omega:X_{n}=2^{n}}\}$, I still don't know how to show $\frac{S_{n}}{n}$  does not converge to $0$ in probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove that for $n=2^k$ the chance of $\frac{S_n}{n}$ being at least $1$ tends to one as $k\rightarrow \infty$. This will, of course, prove that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ cannot converge to $0$ in probability. For it being at least one we need:
$$\frac{S_{2^k}}{2^k}\le1 \iff S_{2^k}\le2^k$$
And for that to happen it is enough that one of $X_k$, $X_{k+1}$, $\dots$, $X_{2^k}$ will be greater than zero. The opposite happens with probability:
$$\frac{k-1}{k} \frac{k}{k+1}\dots\frac{2^k-1}{2^k}=\frac{k-1}{2^k}\rightarrow0$$
So indeed the probability of some variable being positive tends to one, proving the result.

Comment: Maybe it’s $1-e^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer.

Comment: There's a problem, different $X_{j}$ takes different values with different probabilities. This argument cannot apply here

Comment: Indeed. How about now?